# How to import FreeType to my Android Studio NDK project using CMake

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

Hello I am beginner in Android NDK programming and I need some help getting freetype library to work with my project. I've been trying for 3 hours straight to somehow import freetype to my Android Studio project. I searched on the internet and could not find any solution that was working. I downloaded the library and put it in my **cpp** folder of the project.But I don't know how to include freetype. Any help would be appreaciated!

This is how my **CMakeLists.txt** look and for the files that I have added it works for them:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)



project("firstnative")


include_directories(stb/stb_lib
        GoldFlow/Core
        GoldFlow/Graphics
        GoldFlow/Math
        GoldFlow/glm
        GoldFlow/glm/gtc
        GoldFlow/entt
        GoldFlow/physics
        GoldFlow/scripts

    GoldFlow/freetype/include
    GoldFlow/freetype/include/freetype/
    GoldFlow/freetype/include/freetype/config
    GoldFlow/freetype/include/freetype/internal
    GoldFlow/freetype/include/freetype/internal/services
        )



add_library( 
             Native
           
             SHARED


        GoldFlow/Math/GoldMath.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Shader.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Renderer2D.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Camera.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Texture.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/SpriteSheet.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Scene.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/GameObject.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Application.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Controls.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Timer.cpp
        GoldFlow/physics/AABB.cpp
        GoldFlow/physics/Objects.cpp
        GoldFlow/scripts/ControllerScript.cpp
        GoldFlow/scripts/CharacterMovingScript.cpp
        


        native.cpp)


add_library(
    Freetype

    SHARED

    GoldFlow/freetype/src/autofit/autofit.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftbase.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftbbox.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftbdf.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftbitmap.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftcid.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftfstype.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftgasp.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftglyph.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftgxval.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftinit.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftmm.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftotval.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftpatent.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftpfr.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftstroke.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftsynth.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/fttype1.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/base/ftwinfnt.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/bdf/bdf.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/bzip2/ftbzip2.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/cache/ftcache.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/cff/cff.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/cid/type1cid.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/gzip/ftgzip.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/lzw/ftlzw.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/pcf/pcf.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/pfr/pfr.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/psaux/psaux.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/pshinter/pshinter.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/psnames/psnames.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/raster/raster.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/sfnt/sfnt.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/smooth/smooth.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/truetype/truetype.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/type1/type1.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/type42/type42.c
    GoldFlow/freetype/src/winfonts/winfnt.c
```

)

```
find_library( 
              log-lib
              
              log )

find_library(GLES-lib

             GLESv3)



target_link_libraries( 
                       Native
             
                       ${log-lib}
                       ${GLES-lib}
                       ${Freetype}

        )
```

The error I am getting now is this: **C:\Users\infer\AndroidStudioProjects\FirstNative\app\src\main\cpp\GoldFlow\freetype\src\base\ftbdf.c:40:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FT_ERR_PREFIXInvalid_Face_Handle'; did you mean 'FT_Err_Invalid_Face_Handle'?**

Comment: You are welcome to pull freetype for Android (including build script) from https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg. This won't work on Windows, but you can install Ubuntu on your Windows (a.k.a. WSL).

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you for the reply Alex. Is there any other way without having to install ubuntu?

Comment: Install of WSL is easy, it's much cleaner than the old ways with cygwin hacks. You can build your freetype on any Linux machine, or on Mac. Note that you must do it only once: your project will use the generated binary and generated headers.

Comment: You can try to build freetype on Windows through its official `CMakeLists.txt`, again I would recommend to do it as a separate module in your Android project. If you are proficient with CMake, you can setup [subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html) for freetype.

Comment: Thank you I will do it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the solution was very simple. All I did actually was I created directory in cpp folder named freetype and in that dir I've put every freetype file and just added that folder as sub directory in CMake and linked at the end and now eveyrthing works. Here is my CMake:

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

# Declares and names the project.
project("firstnative")

include_directories(stb/stb_lib
        GoldFlow/Core
        GoldFlow/Graphics
        GoldFlow/Math
        GoldFlow/glm
        GoldFlow/glm/gtc
        GoldFlow/entt
        GoldFlow/physics
        GoldFlow/scripts
        GoldFlow/text
        )

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        Native
        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED
        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        GoldFlow/Math/GoldMath.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Shader.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Renderer2D.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Camera.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/Texture.cpp
        GoldFlow/Graphics/SpriteSheet.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Scene.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/GameObject.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Application.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Controls.cpp
        GoldFlow/Core/Timer.cpp
        GoldFlow/physics/AABB.cpp
        GoldFlow/physics/Objects.cpp
        GoldFlow/scripts/ControllerScript.cpp
        GoldFlow/scripts/CharacterMovingScript.cpp
        GoldFlow/text/TextRenderer.cpp
        native.cpp)

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.
#sd

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib
        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log )

find_library(GLES-lib
        GLESv3)

add_subdirectory(freetype)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        Native
        # Links the target library to the log and gl es library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}
        ${GLES-lib}
        freetype
        )
```

Comment: ..I followed this and all works fine on Emulator..however, ON a REAL DEVICE, I am having trouble in getting hold of the library handle (jlong) from JNI back into my android class for further use...it returns a long negative number. ..my simple test was to init ft library, get the handle, get the version with another call with handle as input.. it fails as handle returned seem to be not valid... however, if I do everything in c++, ie, init, use the handle to get the version and return a string with details all works well...any thoughts..